# How to make the image caption background transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
I was trying to change the background of the image caption after the image popup. . When I try to click on the image from the gallery it popup but the caption(Annual function) is in black.
```

Need to make the background transparent of the caption. When I use any property for making it transparent it becomes white. Caption should have a see-through background.

And I know no one use table to make a website. But I had to do it.
Need to make the background transparent of the caption. When I use any property for making it transparent it becomes white. Caption should have a see-through background.

```js
    function openModal() {
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function closeModal() {
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
```

```css
* {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        .table1 {
          font-family: verdana;
          font-size: 10px;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
    
        .menu {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #F8CF44;
        }
    
        .menu:hover {
          color: white;
        }
    
        p {
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: small;
          color: white;
          margin-top: 14px;
          margin-left: 13px;
          margin-right: 10px;
        }
    
        .img2 {
          margin-right: 48px;
          margin-top: 17px;
          margin-left: 25px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    
    
        a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: black;
        }
    
        .footer {
          margin-left: 16px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
          color: black;
        }
    
        .footer2:hover {
          color: white;
        }
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    
    .row > .column {
      padding: 0 8px;
    }
    
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .modal {
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 35px;
    left: 407px;
    top: 151px;
    width: 687px;
    height: 76%;
    overflow: auto;
    
    
    }
    
    
    .modal-content {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 1200px;
    animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.3s;
    }
    #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%; 
        text-align: center;
       color: #ccc;
        padding: 6px 0;
    background-color: rgba(9,9,9,9.9);
     
    height:18px;
        
    }
    .prev:hover,
    .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    
    
    
    .close {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: 33px;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #999;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    
    .prev,
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
    
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
    
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    
    img {
      margin-bottom: -4px;
    }
    
    
    .demo {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    
    .active,
    .demo:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    img.hover-shadow {
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
```

```html
    <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="780" background="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x200" width="374" valign="top" style="color:white; font-size: small; font-family: 
    
    Verdana;height:512px;background-position-x: right; background-size: 783px 1357px;">
          <tr>
            <td><img src="images\top.jpg" width="780" height="108"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="780">
                <tr>
                  <td width="159" height="265" valign="top" background="images\extra.jpg">
                    <table class="table1" style="line-height: 197%;margin-left: 20px;margin-top: 0px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align=left>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="vision.html">Vision </a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="history.html">History</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="location.html">Location</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="organisation.html">Organisation</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="curriculum.html">Curriculum</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="school_uniform.html">School Uniform</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="teaching_staff.html">Teaching Staff</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="facilities.html">Facilities</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="activities.html">Activities</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="rules.html">Rules</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="register_online.html">Register online</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="photogallery.html">Photogallery</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a class="menu" href="site_map.html">Site Map</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="621">
                      <tr>
                        <td><img border="0" src="images\photogallery_img.jpg" width="621" height="34"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="581">
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="center" height="30" style="font-size:14px; color:white;"><b>ANNUAL
                              FUNCTION<br>
                              <br>
                            </b></td>
                        </tr>
    
                        <tr>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="column">
                              <td>
                                <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x100" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor" >
                              </td>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column">
                              <td>
                                <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x200" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
                              </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" height="20"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <div class="column">
                            <td>
                              <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x250" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                          </div>
                          <div class="column">
                            <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x100" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
                  </td>
                  </div>
                </tr>
    
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
     <div class="modal-content">
    
          <div class="mySlides">
          
             <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x100" style="width:100%">
    <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
          </div>
    
           <div class="mySlides">
      
             <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x200" style="width:100%">
    <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
           </div>
    
           <div class="mySlides">
     
             <img src=https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x250" style="width:100%">
    <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
           </div>
        
            <div class="mySlides">
             <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/100x100" style="width:100%">
    <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
            </div>
        
    
             <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
             <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    
           <div class="caption-container">
                  <p id="caption" ></p>
           </div>
    
    
    
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
                </div>
    
        </table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" width="780" background="images\bottom_img.jpg" height="27" style="font-size:x-small;
    font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold;"><b class="footer" style="margin-left: 18px;">Powered by <a href="http://www.catchal.net" target="_blank" class="footer2">Catchcal.net</a><b></td>
    
        </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
```

Comment: Side note, don't use [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: In HTML, [IDs must be unique to the DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page); i.e. they cannot be repeated.

Comment: There is a lot of code here, I've put up a suggestion for a way forward for you in an answer, but in future it would be good if you could post a snippet which demonstrates the particular problem. Also you might be well advised to put your code through a validator as @showdev has pointed out there are HTML errors. In this case you can probably just swap id="caption" for class="caption".

Answer (score 0):

Click on an image then go to your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see what styling is being applied to the caption.

You will find this:

```
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 6px 0;
    background-color: rgba(9,9,9,9.9);
    height: 18px;
}
```

You can see the background-color is being set, not quite to absolute black but very close to it (and I'm not sure why there is a 9.9 as the fourth (opacity) parameter).

Anyway, get rid of that setting of the background-color and replace with `background-color: transparent` if that is what you want.